# How to select random rows from R data frame to include all distinct values of two columns

Tags: r, random, dplyr

I want to select a random sample of rows from a large R data frame `df` (around 10 million rows) in such a way that all distinct values of two columns are included in the resulting sample. `df` looks like:

```
StoreID      WEEK      Units      Value          ProdID
2001         1         1          3.5            20702
2001         2         2          3              20705
2002         32        3          6              23568
2002         35        5          15             24025
2003         1         2          10             21253
```

I have the following unique values in the respective columns: `StoreID`: 1433 and `WEEK`: 52. When I generate a random sample of rows from `df`, I must have at least one row each for each `StoreID` and each `WEEK` value.

I used the function `sample_frac` in `dplyr` in various trials but that does not ensure that all distinct values of `StoreID` and `WEEK` are included at least once in the resulting sample. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to group the desired columns before sampling rows. The last line will return one random row for each unique storeID-week pairing.

```r
df <- data.frame(storeid=sample(c(2000:2010),1000,T),
                 week=sample(c(1:52),1000,T),
                 value=runif(1000))

# count number of duplicated storeid-week pairs
df %>% count(storeid,week) %>% filter(n>1)

df %>% group_by(storeid,week) %>% sample_n(1)

# A tibble: 468 x 3
# Groups:   storeid, week [468]
   storeid  week  value
     <int> <int>  <dbl>
 1    2000     1 0.824 
 2    2000     2 0.0987
 3    2000     6 0.916 
 4    2000     8 0.289 
 5    2000     9 0.610 
 6    2000    11 0.0807
 7    2000    12 0.592 
 8    2000    13 0.849 
 9    2000    14 0.0181
10    2000    16 0.182 
# ... with 458 more rows
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I have read the problem correctly. I would have tried the following using sample function.
Assuming your dataframe is called MyDataFrame  and is two dimensional, I would have done it like this.

```
RandomizedDF <- MyDataFrame[sample(dim(MyDataFrame)[1],dim(MyDataFrame)[1],replace=FALSE),]
```

Let me know if this is what you wanted or something else?

Comment: This command returns the original data frame itself, no sampling occurred. To clarify the problem further, I have 1433 unique StoreID and 52 unique WEEK. So, when I sample I should have at least one row for each StoreID-WEEK combination (1433*52=74516). That is, if I sample say 10% of the 10 million rows in original data frame, they should contain 74516 distinct StoreID-WEEK combinations. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Do you have a prior reason to be convinced that those 1433*52=74516 rows exist in the dataset (as unique rows)? If yes, then I will just modify the command just that the right hand side they are passed inside the unique function. Something like RandomizedDF <- unique(MyDataFrame[sample(dim(MyDataFrame)[1],dim(MyDataFrame)[1],replace=FALSE),]). I am still not sure however, if I understand the problem correctly. Sorry if I am still off track to your requirement.

Comment: Yes, I know that for every StoreID there is a transaction in every WEEK, so I am sure about the 74516 rows. Your suggestion did not work unfortunately.